# Does this have a name?

Tags: header-line

I'm trying to change the color of this part of the UI (top heading bar) in my theme file:

[image]

Does this have a specific name that I could use to change its color?

Other parts of the interface are referred to like so, but this element isn't there:

```
   `(cursor ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-accent))))
   `(fringe ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-bg))))
   `(region ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-gray))))
   `(highlight ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-gray))))
   `(hl-line ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-bg-hl))))
   `(vertical-border ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-mono-3))))
   `(secondary-selection ((t (:background ,atom-one-dark-bg-1))))
   `(query-replace ((t (:inherit (isearch)))))
   `(minibuffer-prompt ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-silver))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's the **header line**.

You can customize its appearance using **`M-x customize-face header-line`**.

See also the Elisp manual, node [Header Lines](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Header-Lines.html).